# Virtual address page replacement with LRU policy - use case

Tags: caching, memory-management, operating-system, tlb

How can I use LRU page replacement if the following virtual addresses are accessed sequentially:

```
 0xdeadbeef,
 0xcdacdacd, 
 0xbad2ceed,
 0xcdacd123, 
 0xdeadb341, 
 0x34312315.
```

How many page fault will be there??

The info on the memory management system in question:

- Hierarchical 2 level array
- 4 frames physical address
- 4 Frames virtual memory of 4KB each.
- TLB 2 place

Answer (score 2):

LRU - Least Recently used:

TLB 2 places - only 2 entries.

- Take lower 4k of value.  `eef` for first entry.  Add it to TLB.
- Next value, `acd` not in table, add it.
- Next value, `eed` not in table and table is full, replace `eef` with this value.
- Next value, `123` not in table and table is full, replace `acd` with this value.
- etc.

No cache hits whatsoever with your above test values if I use the lower 12-bits as my hash.

[A page describing your requirements](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0640/SGI_Developer/books/OrOn2_PfTune/sgi_html/ch06.html).

Is this enough info for you?

Comment: a very fast cache memory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer